# Error when trying to send HTTP status code in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, cowboy

I am a Phoenix/Elixir beginner and am trying to write an API to allow users to sign up in my application.

The API endpoint works as expected unless I try to set the HTTP status code of the response. When I include lines A, B and C (indicated in the code below), I get a `FunctionClauseError` with the message `no function clause matching in :cowboy_req.status/1`.

The complete error message is as follows:

```
[error] #PID<0.344.0> running App.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: POST /api/user/
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :cowboy_req.status/1
        (cowboy) src/cowboy_req.erl:1272: :cowboy_req.status(451)
        (cowboy) src/cowboy_req.erl:1202: :cowboy_req.response/6
        (cowboy) src/cowboy_req.erl:933: :cowboy_req.reply_no_compress/8
        (cowboy) src/cowboy_req.erl:888: :cowboy_req.reply/4
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/conn.ex:34: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Conn.send_resp/4
        (plug) lib/plug/conn.ex:356: Plug.Conn.send_resp/1
        (app) web/controllers/user_controller.ex:1: App.UserController.action/2
        (app) web/controllers/user_controller.ex:1: App.UserController.phoenix_controller_app/2
        (app) lib/app/endpoint.ex:1: App.Endpoint.instrument/4
        (app) lib/phoenix/router.ex:261: App.Router.dispatch/2
        (app) web/router.ex:1: App.Router.do_call/2
        (app) lib/app/endpoint.ex:1: App.Endpoint.phoenix_app/1
        (app) lib/plug/debugger.ex:122: App.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (app) lib/app/endpoint.ex:1: App.Endpoint.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
        (cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

My code is as follows:

```
defmodule App.UserController do
  use App.Web, :controller

  import Ecto.Changeset

  alias App.User
  alias App.Session

  def create(conn, params) do
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, params)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, _user} ->
        email = get_field(changeset, :email)
        password = get_field(changeset, :password)

        # Log on user upon sign up
        session_changeset = Session.changeset(%Session{
          email: email,
          password: password
        })
        result = Repo.insert(session_changeset)

        case result do
          {:ok, session} ->
            conn
            |> put_resp_cookie("SID", session.session_id)
            |> put_status(201)  # line A
            |> render("signup.json", data: %{
                 changeset: changeset
               })
          {:error, changeset} ->
            conn
            |> put_status(251)  # line B
            |> render("signup.json", data: %{
                 changeset: changeset
               })
        end
      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(451)  # line C
        |> render("signup.json", data: %{
             changeset: changeset
           })
    end
  end

end
```

Why does this happen and where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit** as of 22nd October 2016 this is now possible on Plug master. Here is the relevant section of the docs for reference:

> ### Custom status codes
>
> Plug allows status codes to be overridden or added in order to allow new codes   not directly specified by Plug or
>   its adapters. Adding or overriding a status   code is done through the
>   Mix configuration of the `:plug` application. For   example, to
>   override the existing 404 reason phrase for the 404 status code
>   ("Not Found" by default) and add a new 451 status code, the following
>   config   can be specified:
>
> ```
>   config :plug, :statuses, %{
>     404 => "Actually This Was Found",
>     451 => "Unavailable For Legal Reasons"
>   }
> ```
>
> As this configuration is Plug specific, Plug will need to be recompiled for   the changes to take place: this will not happen
>   automatically as dependencies   are not automatically recompiled when
>   their configuration changes.
>   To recompile Plug:
>
> ```
> MIX_ENV=prod mix deps.compile plug
> ```
>
> The atoms that can be used in place of the status code in many functions are   inflected from the
>   reason phrase of the status code. With the above   configuration, the
>   following will all work:
>
> ```
>   put_status(conn, :not_found)                     # 404
>   put_status(conn, :actually_this_was_found)       # 404
>   put_status(conn, :unavailable_for_legal_reasons) # 451
> ```
>
> Even though 404 has been overridden, the `:not_found` atom can still be
>   used   to set the status to 404 as well as the new atom
>   `:actually_this_was_found`   inflected from the reason phrase
>   "Actually This Was Found".

---

Cowboy manually specifies the HTTP response code and matches on the integer specified.

https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/blob/1.0.x/src/cowboy_req.erl#L1318

A binary is permitted, however doing:

```
conn
|> put_status("451 Unavailable For Legal Reasons")
```

Won't work as plug only permits an integer or a known atom.

This should probably be considered a bug. You can try and get a pull request into Cowboy in the file I linked.

If getting a PR merged into Cowboy isn't possible, it can also be performed in Plug for the Cowboy adapter by transforming the status (this is a naive solution):

```
status = if (status == 451) do
  "451 Unavailable For Legal Reasons"
else
  status
end
```

In this file https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/master/lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/conn.ex#L33

See also https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/issues/965 and https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/issues/451

Comment: Thanks for the help and for opening up an issue for this. For now, I would just stick with known HTTP codes and send the custom codes as part of my JSON response.

Comment: @MohideenImranKhan I sent as PR for this and it has been merged into master, so this will be available in the next release of Plug. https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/pull/470